# Type of Machine for use Subversion on Compute Engine

Tags: svn, google-compute-engine

I'd like to install Subversion on Google Compute Engine, for use in a team of ten programers so what Type of Machine choose is recomended, at low cost?

f1-micro is sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that svn doesn't need a lot of CPU, so f1-micro is probably sufficient. The f1-micros are a shared CPU, if you want a dedicated core, look at the n-series machine types, with n1-standard-1 being the smallest. See the docs for [pricing details](https://developers.google.com/compute/pricing).

I'd recommend a fairly large data disk, since Persistent Disk I/O scales up with disk size. See the [Compute Engine Disks: Price, Performance, and Persistence](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/compute-engine-disks-price-performance-and-persistence) blog post for more details.